# Efficient way of flashing images in python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, timer, frequency

What would the most efficient way of flashing images be in python?

Currently I have an infinite while loop that calls sleep at the end, then uses matplotlib to display an image. However I can't get matplotlib to replace the current image, I instead have to close then show again which is slow. I'd like to flash sequences of images as precisely as possible at a set frequency.

I'm opens to solutions that use other libraries to do the replacement in place.

Comment: Try using the `Image` widget in `Kivy`.

Comment: Matplotlib is one option (in which case you'd use `FuncAnimation`). Also `pyqtgraph` would allow for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a library called PsychoPy. It can guarantee that everything is drawn and allows you to control when a window is drawn (a frame) with the window.frame() function.

Answer (score 1):

Using openCV you could use this to iterate through images and show them

```py
for img in images:
    # Show the image (will replace previously displayed images
    # with the same title)
    cv2.imshow('window title', img)

    # Wait 1000ms before showing the next image and if the user
    # pressed 'q', close the window and stop looping through the dataset 
    if cv2.waitKey(1000) & 0xFF == ord('q'): 
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: Any idea how I can guarantee the images are shown at a certain frequency, and get a ping immediately after the image is displayed?

Comment: `waitKey()` will wait for the specified delay in milliseconds, unless there has been a key press. In this example, it will only wait for a keypress on the letter 'q'. As for guaranteeing the images are shown at a certain frequency:
*"Since the OS has a minimum time between switching threads, the function will not wait exactly delay ms, it will wait at least delay ms, depending on what else is running on your computer at that time"*. Link to the documentation: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#waitkey